# échapper + objet direct

Tags: grammaire, transitivité

Shortly after [3:22 in this video](https://youtu.be/w6U0lCSjcpk?t=202), Daniel Lavoie mistakenly uses « échapper » with a COD instead of a COI and then corrects himself.

> – Quand ç'a démarré, « Notre Dame de Paris », c'était complètement fou.
> – Vous étiez des superstars en France.
> – Ah ouais, on était les Beatles. C'était vraiment la folie. À l'époque, je me souviens, il y avait mille personnes qui nous attendaient à la fin des spectacles. **Il fallait courir pour les échapper ... leur échapper.**

How common is this type of error?

- Is it specific to *échapper*, that it's a word whose transitivity is sometimes mistaken, perhaps signifying that it's in flux? (Arguably, it would more closely mirror the English "escape them".)
- Is it something that often happens with [verbe] à [COI] constructions? Perhaps especially with preverbal pronouns?
- Is it a totally random fluke, a slip that you'd never expect to hear?

My aim here is to distinguish between "Nobody would flub such a rule except a Franco-Manitoban who's been spending too much time working on his next album of English songs" and (yet another case of) "Oh, right, we learn that in school, but people get it wrong all the time in real life."

Comment: Here's some stats: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les+%C3%A9chapper%2C+leur+%C3%A9chapper&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: It's more of the first case, I don't think it's quite common/accepted to do that "mistake". Not saying it doesn't happen, but can't say it's becoming mainstream either, and ngrams seem to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some [stats](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les%20%C3%A9chapper%2C%20leur%20%C3%A9chapper&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) for *échapper*, courtesy of the google ngrams, fwiw, for the case of writing, and without having proofread the examples it returns. They seem to indicate that *leur échapper* is still the most common form, by far (given all the limitations of the ngrams). However, here's [more ngram stats](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les%20%C3%A9chapper&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) that show that usage of *les échapper* is increasing (although it is still very marginal compared to *leur échapper*).

I think that in general, it's a mistake of the speaker that can happen, but that is not necessarily on its way to becoming mainstream. It may cast the speaker as either coming from the *banlieues* or exhibiting a regionalism. It's still grating on average. I don't think it rises yet to the case of a rule you learn in school but flout every day in mainstream French without thinking about it.

Comment: *“It may cast the speaker as either coming from the banlieues”* Pouvez-vous expliciter svp ? N'importe quelle personne parlant français pourrait faire cette erreur, *banlieusarde* ou non.

Comment: @A.L Oui, je suis d'accord, et c'est pourquoi j'ai dit "may". Pour moi, ça pourrait sonner _banlieusard_ **peut-être**.

Answer (score 3):

> except a Franco-Manitoban who's been spending too much time working on his next album of English songs

This is the most rational explanation, yes. It is an extremely rare mistake to make in French, simply because the type of transitiveness is something deeply ingrained in your mind since childhood, especially for such a basic verb, and the pronoun rolls off the tongue.

Maybe when your tongue slips on something complex like

> Il a fallu les aider pour les faire [les/leur] échapper

but for a simple structure like Lavoie's sentence it's very doubtful.

Comment: That's what I thought, but then I've been having even the fundamentals/basics questioned by users around here sometimes (e.g. regionality of Donne-moi-le vs. Donne-le-moi ...)

Comment: @LukeSawczak watching the video it really struck as an anglicism, and a mistake "only" a French Canadian would make. (If not "only", at the very least it's a mistake that's much, much more likely to happen to someone who speaks and listens to English very frequently, as a Franco-Manitoban would)

Answer (score 1):

It is common but not at all particular to the verb "échapper". It is a consequence of  the incertitude in the speaker's mind as to what will best render what he has in mind and of lauching himself too soon onto a given grammatical course, so to speak. For instance he could have chosen to use the verb "éviter", and this choice of verb would have called for "les"; however, it occurred to him that "échapper"  communicated the idea better than anything else, and so he realized that the pronoun wasn't right and had to be corrected.

It is more likely to happen to inexperienced speakers, but it can also happen to speakers used to speaking in public, in particular to speakers that find it important to come up as often as possible with the mot juste.

This type of rushed phrasing is however occurring  in most cases with an hesitation after the pronoun, and the verb is not spoken twice.